# Asp.net web API Get method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use **select** query in this `Get` method, because when I search the customer with id 4, it just shows its first record not all records, here is my method, i'm using simple *mvc* services.

I think that it shows only the first record because of #FirstOrDefault option , can anyone recommend me what query I should use or any other options?

```
`  public sales_order Get(int id)
    {
        using (project_smartEntities entities = new project_smartEntities())
        {
            entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return entities.sales_orders.FirstOrDefault(e => e.customer_id == id);
        }


    }`
```

Comment: So... You expect there to be multiple matching records and want to return them all?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, `.FirstOrDefault()` returns the *first* (or default) matching record.  (For reference types, the default is `null`.)  If you want to find many records which match the query, you'd use the SQL-aptly-named `.Where()` instead:

```
return entities.sales_orders.Where(e => e.customer_id == id);
```

Since this returns a collection of objects instead of a single object, this would also of course necessitate changing the method's return type:

```
public IEnumerable<sales_order> Get(int id)
```

(Or any other applicable collection type.  `IEnumerable<>` is just often the simplest.)

Comment: "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."     It gives this error

Comment: @RafiaZaheer: Is there an inner exception with details about the serialization error?